# Crear registro en BD con Identity en ASP.net core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, identity

Estoy intentando crear un registro en ASP.net utilizando EF core e Identity. He creado los modelos, la migración ha sido correcta y se ha creado la BD con todas las entidades.

Una de las entidades es Categorias, la cual hereda de IdentityRole ya que quiero que sean los roles que va a tener cada usuario:

```
namespace AppTurnos2.Entidades
{
   public class Categoria : IdentityRole<string>
   {
  
   }
}
```

Como veis no tiene propiedades, ya que quiero utilizar el Id y el Name por defecto de Identity.

La cuestión viene ahora. Tengo una vista con un formulario que guarda los inputs en un modelo, y con esos datos quiero crear un usuario, asignándole la categoría que se seleccione junto con el Nombre, apellidos, email, etc. Para ello he creado la siguiente acción en el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registro (RegistroViewModel modelo)
    {
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) 
        { 
            return View(modelo);
        }
        // Verificar si la categoría existe en la base de datos
        var categoria = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(modelo.Categoria);

        // Si la categoría no existe, la creamos
        if (categoria is null)
        {
            categoria = new Categoria { Name = modelo.Categoria };
            var createRoleResult = await roleManager.CreateAsync(categoria);

            if (!createRoleResult.Succeeded)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Registro", modelo); 
            }
        }
        var usuario = new Usuario() { 
            
            Email = modelo.Email,
            UserName = modelo.Nombre,
            PhoneNumber = modelo.Telefono,
            PasswordHash = modelo.Password,
            Apellidos = modelo.Apellidos,
            Dni = modelo.Dni,
            CategoriaId = modelo.Categoria
           
        };

        var resultado = await userManager.CreateAsync(usuario, modelo.Password);

        if (resultado.Succeeded)
        {
            /* Asignar el rol correspondiente (Enfermero, Tecnico o Administrador) al 
            usuario*/

            var categoriaExiste = await roleManager.FindByNameAsync(modelo.Categoria);
            if (categoriaExiste != null)
            {
                await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(usuario, categoriaExiste.Name);
            }

            // Redirigir al usuario después de un registro exitoso
            return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
        }

        /* Si llegamos aquí, hubo errores, volvemos a mostrar el formulario con los 
        errores*/

        foreach (var error in resultado.Errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
        }

        return View(modelo);
    

    }
```

El mensaje que me sale de error es el siguiente para la tabla Categoria:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to track an entity of type
> 'Categoria' because its primary key property 'Id' is null.

No entiendo por qué es null y en que parte de la configuración falla. Tenía entendido que Identity proporcionaría este Id si no especificas uno y por lo tanto, al crear la tabla le adjudica uno.

Me he dado cuenta de que se crea el registro en la tabla Usuario y Rol en la tabla Categorias, pero sin embargo, las tablas AspNetUsers Y AspNetUserRoles están vacías.

Muestro la clase Usuarios y mi DbContext para ver si me pueden ayudar:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Globalization;

namespace AppTurnos2.Entidades
{
  public class Usuario : IdentityUser<string>
  {
    
    [Required]
    public string Apellidos { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] 
    public override string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 9, ErrorMessage = "El DNI debe 
    tener exactamente 9 dígitos.")]
    public string Dni { get; set; }

    public string CategoriaId { get; set; }
    public Categoria Categoria { get; set; }
    public List<Mensaje> Mensajes { get; set; } 
    public List<Notificacion> Notificaciones { get; set; } 
    public List<RegistroJornada> Jornadas { get; set; }
    public List<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesSolicitante {get; set;} 
    public List<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesSolicitado {get; set; }
    public ArchivoAdjunto ArchivoAdjunto {get; set;}
    }
  }
```

El DbContext es el siguiente:

```
namespace AppTurnos2
{
public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext (DbContextOptions options) : 
    base(options)
    {

    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder 
    optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder 
    modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
        .Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
        .Property(e => e.Id).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
       .Property(p => p.UserId).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>()
       .Property(p => p.RoleId).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Usuario>()
     .HasOne(u => u.Categoria)
     .WithMany()
     .HasForeignKey(u => u.CategoriaId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Mensaje>()
    .HasOne(m => m.Emisor)
    .WithMany(u => u.Mensajes)
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.EmisorId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<SolicitudCambio>()
    .HasOne(m => m.UsuarioSolicitado)    
    .WithMany(u => u.SolicitudesSolicitado) 
    .HasForeignKey(m => m.UsuarioSolicitadoId)
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        
    }

    public DbSet<Turno> Turnos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EstadoSolicitud> EstadoSolicitudes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SolicitudCambio> SolicitudesCambios { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RegistroJornada> RegistroJornadas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Notificacion> Notificaciones { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Mensaje> Mensajes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ArchivoAdjunto> ArchivosAdjuntos { get; set; }
    }
}
```